# How to write the text file using sensetalk - eggplant functional

Tags: android, eggplant

I am currently working on eggplant functional and need your support in order to create a text file and append it whenever there is any action performed in the script. I will be using this text file for logging step by step results. can you please help ?

Comment: Thank you AndySavage, I am able to create a notepad file now :)

Answer (score 2):

To append information to a log file, just do this:

```
put "this is a new log entry" & return after file "/path/to/log/file"
```

If the file doesn't exist, it will be created. After that, a new line will be added each time.

If you'll be doing this a lot you may want to create a custom handler that you can call. This one puts the date and time before each log entry:

```
to logEvent theEvent
  put the abbreviated international time & tab & theEvent & return after file "/path/to/log/file"
end logEvent
```

Then call it like this:

```
logEvent "Interesting stuff happened."
```

Answer (score 0):

`return` and the other options (`linefeed, etc.`) don't work for me. The only way to get a new line is with `crlf` (Carriage Return and Line Feed).

I'm using Windows 10.

Put:

```
dataLine & crlf
```

After:

```
file fullPath
```